# Different Font-Color in GWT-Label

Tags: gwt, colors, label

Is it possible to have two different font-colors in a gwt-label?

Example:

```
Label titleLabel = new Label(ticket.getTicketType().getName()+" - <<"+art+">>");
```

The second part of the label should be red.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `HTML` widget:

```java
titleLabel = new HTML(SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(ticket.getTicketType().getName())
    + " - <span style='color: red'>&lt;&lt;"
    + SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(art)
    + "&gt;&gt;</span>");
```

To make it slightly more readable, I'd use a `SafeHtmlTemplates` (and as a bonus, it'll check your HTML syntax, and automatically `htmlEscape` your strings so you don't risk to miss one, so it's safer):

```java
interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
   @Template("{0} - <span style='color: red'>&lt;&lt;{1}&gt;&gt;</span>")
   SafeHtml title(String ticketTypeName, String art);
}
static final Template TEMPLATE = GWT.create(Template.class)

...

titleLabel = new HTML(TEMPLATE.title(ticket.getTicketType().getName(), art));
```

I'd also replace the `style='color: red'` with a `class='{2}'` and a `CssResource`, but that's just a bonus, and mostly a detail.